# Is there a SE site about Clothing Industry?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am trying to make some geek T-shirts that show a lot of mathematical or chemical formulas, and I find [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) a perfect SE site for me to get information about design, so my question is there a SE site focus on Clothing Industry?

Comment: I don't think there is. Do you have an example of a question you'd like to ask? Perhaps we can find a suitable site.

Comment: You can proposed such site on http://area51.stackexchange.com/ with some example questions which should be acceptable. Hope this will be in proposed site there.

Comment: I really doubt such a site would have a large enough audience to be successful...